# Java SOAP/REST webservices : client timeout but server does not rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services

I have a java client app and a java server app.
My client can have network slowdown.

My client performs SOAP webservices to my server app. The problem is that sometimes the client reach its timeout (40sec) because the network is really, really bad.

For the client app this request is a fail, and it retry the same call a bit later. But the server had already integrated the data from client, and I get violated keys error from my ORM.

I do not want to prolong the timeout on the client side.

My question is: when the client timeout, is there a way to rollback everything on the server side ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the options to solve it is to set some flag/status in the database when request is accepted by server. Something like `inProcessing`. And change this flag to `Complete` after successful data processing.

When client will retry the same call later you can check this flag and if `flag=inProcessing or Complete` don't do any date processing.

Comment: I do not want to be stateful. What I have done is that I put a smaller timeout on server side (e.g 30sec) a bit more on client side (e.g 40sec). In case of network problems the server timeout the first, and rollback all

Comment: @psv it wouldn't work if the client forcibly close connection before server timeout. The state is stored in the database. You store the state in db anyway after processing.